# auto assign a static ip on RPi3

Tags: raspberry-pi, static-ip-address

This is my first post but I have read a lot of great answers from this community, so first of all, thanks to all the people who indirectly had helped me.

At this time I want to know how can I achieve the following;

I'm working with a Raspberry Pi 3 using the last stable Raspbian and I will access internet via a router connected trough eth, not WiFi, so the router will assign it an IP through DHCP.

What I want to do it's to "automatically" and without my intervention, a script or something that can take that assigned data (IP, DNS, Subnet mask, etc) and use it as values to ask for a static IP the next time the RPi3 reboots (also disabling DHCP).

So can someone please help me to know if this can be done and how?

Thanks!